# PHP append array to array reference

Tags: php, reference

I have a function which return reference to an array (globals are used for simplicity, actually these arrays are elements of some big tree structure):

```
$array1;
$array2;

function &foo($arg){
  //deduce from $arg reference to which array should be returned
  if(...) {
    global $array1;
    return $array1;
  } else {
    global $array2;
    return $array2;
  }
}
```

Then I need to append another array to the one returned with this function (so that initial array was changed):

```
$arrayToAppend = array('a','b');
$arrayToChange = &foo($arg);
$arrayToChange = array_merge($arrayToChange, $arrayToAppend);
```

Is it correct syntax for what I want to do? Does it change referenced array? Are there any pitfalls I should know? (pitfalls about reference stuff, not about merging assosiative arrays etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things up. You should only use & in front of a parameter in your function (if the parameter is a simple type, so no object) and you want the content of that parameter to change.

Example:

```
<?php

$arrayToChange = array('a', 'b');
$arrayToAppend = array('c', 'd');
mergeArrays($arrayToChange, $arrayToAppend); 

// $arrayToChange will now contain 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' 

function mergeArrays(& $array, $arrayToAppend)
{
  $array = array_merge($array, $arrayToAppend);
} 

//Note: This is not the way you should do it. 
//A function best returns a result. 
//This just illustrates how you can change the content of a parameter
```

Comment: I don't want to change any parameter inside function. Function is responsible only for "choosing' array and returning reference to it.

Comment: I now understand what you want. Based on a condition you want the reference (pointer) returned by the function. I think what you do is correct. I doubt you win much by just returning the reference. You could simply return the array what is done most of the time. You worry about memory usage or speed?

Comment: No, the thing is that I need to change the actual array that is part of big tree structure of such arrays. Function `foo($arg)` is a finder function (which array to change) that is reused for many possible changing operations.